# How can I save the current contents of less to a file?

Tags: bash, pipe, less

If I've piped the results of a command to `less` and then decided that I want to save the contents to a file, is this possible?

I've tried setting a mark `a` at the end of the buffer, and then returning to the top and using `|avi` to send the whole contents to `vi`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Your original technique would work if you instructed vi to load from stdin, by doing `|avi -`.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

On my system, `man less` says

```
s filename
       Save the input to a file.  This only works if  the  input  is  a
       pipe, not an ordinary file.
```

Works for me!

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't work for me - typing 's' moves the window by one line. I'm on a Mac.

Comment: @benroth: You probably have a `lesskey` file that changes the normal commands. See `man lesskey`

Comment: `s` does not work for me either, but `-o file` does.

Comment: And why on earth isn't this mentioned when I type 'h' to get interactive help? +1 if you've read the interactive help and therefore didn't think to consult `man less`...

Comment: See `man less` for the `lesskey` details (not `man lesskey`).

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch Maybe this was added since you wrote your comment but I can say that it's in the version I have (530, 05 Dec 2017).

Comment: @comfreak: Yes it is in less 487 in Ubuntu 18.04 but not in less 481 in Debian 9/stretch/stable

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer doesn't work on the Mac -- as @benroth says, pressing `s` just moves down a line -- but you can use a different method.

In `less --help`:

```
|Xcommand            Pipe file between current pos & mark X to shell command.
```

and

```
A mark is any upper-case or lower-case letter.
Certain marks are predefined:
     ^  means  beginning of the file
     $  means  end of the file
```

So if you go to the top of the buffer (`<`) and then:

```
|$cat > /tmp/foo.txt
```

the contents of the buffer will be written out to `/tmp/foo.txt`.

Comment: This method can be especially useful when you want to pipe the current buffer being viewed through another command.

Answer (score 9):

When your `less` is opened, you can save the complete output to a file.
Like `vim`, less supports commands.

Just type the key `s`, then `less` will ask you the name of the file where you wish to save the content, just type the file name and then type `Enter`.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do a slightly different thing: write just the currently visible portion of the text to a file.  I found that I could do so using the "|" operator, specifying "." as the mark, and `cat >/tmp/mycopy` as the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

No if you have started less, but if you know before yu want to send it to less and a file then you can use the tee command

```
command | tee out_file | less
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I'm specifically looking how to do it if I'm already in less

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes a tad too late I believe. But just for reference,
in response to benroth's concern above: For OSX users there's always the option to dump the contents of the pager to a log file by using the option "-l" (read *DASH ELL*) at the colon prompt.

The pager will ask for a log file. Key it and press [CR]

Answer (score -1):

Use the `>` operator. For example: `less foo.bar > output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @Dror, but I'm already in the less application, not at the bash prompt any more

Comment: A valuable contribution to the Q/A.  Rather than start a totally separate question, people needing a method to script multiple files through the **Less Viewer** can benefit a lot.  Saved me hours of work (after a lot of searching).  Thanks!