# Cygwin "less" pager: "s" command not saving text to file

Tags: cygwin, less

According to [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/290908), `less`'s `s` command should save the paged text to file.  When I press `s`, I am asked for a log file.  I provide a fill path `~/tmp/less_blah.txt`, and the prompt then goes away.  The specified file, however, never appears, even after I quit `less`.  Is there anything I can do to track down the source of the problem?

Comment: Works for me. Does the directory `~/tmp` exist?

Comment: Just FYI: While I don't have cygwin available now, the `less` on my Mac also does not process the `s` correctly, although the man-page documents it. For me, the behaviour is different from yours: When I press `s`, I'm not even are asked for a file. BTW, in your case, I would try to avoid the `~`. The docs don't pretend that they would expand the tilde to your homedirectory.

Comment: @Chris Davies: Yes, folder `~/tmp` exists. If I specify a path that includes a nonexistent folder, `less` says "Cannot write to `The/Bad/Path`".

Comment: @user1934428: Strange, but `s` works today, even with `~` in the path.  Since I just discovered `less`'s `s` command, I expect to be using it a lot.  I'll try to suss out the conditions under which `s` works, but nothing I varied could make the problem recur today.